# Standard deviation for proportion with huge denominator

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, large-data

My question involves finding the standard deviation of a ratio when the denominator is huge.

The standard formula $$\sqrt{\frac{p(1−p)}{n}}$$ yields a number that is almost zero. The context is computing a Days of Therapy ratio per days at risk (DAR) for a combined set of hospitals. We will typically have a value for DAR in the tens of thousands, making the n very large.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: "Alternative" to what?  The SD depends on how the ratio was measured and on your modeling assumptions, so we need some context to provide reasonable answers.  Please provide that.

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3274998/standard-deviation-for-proportion-with-huge-denominator.

Comment: That formula is the for the standard error of a sample proportion. It's not clear that's what you want. It seems like each individual gets a ratio, and you want the standard deviation of those ratios (i.e., to know how much spread there is in the ratios across the many individuals in your sample). Is that correct?

Comment: when you say "not meaningful" what meaning are you trying to give th SD?

Comment: my think is you do not believe your estimate can be as accurate as your SD is saying. as this is not a "mistake" with calculation (the largest SD you can get with $n=10000$ is $0.005$), it must be a mistake with your assumptions - probably independence between units contributing to the 0-1 trials

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Regarding the data, I suppose it is not independent Bernoulli trials. The numerator is the sum of the days on a particular drug for all patients at a hospital, and the denominator is the sum of all "days at risk" for these patients. Days at risk basically means days of hospital stay. So the ratio is really a ratio of sums of count data I suppose.

Comment: To Noah, no, each patient does not receive a ratio. See my other comment that I added just now.